# Windows Server Backup failing: Parameter is incorrect?

Tags: backup, windows, vss

For a while now I've been experiencing trouble with trying to back up our server using the built-in server backup tool: It would fail for some reason about a shadow copy, but would work if I just chose to do the individual drives (C:, D:).

Lately though, it has started acting up and is now failing out of the blue with this:

[image: Backup failure showing failure due to parameter is incorrect]

I don't know what's causing it, and I've been searching around on Google but haven't had any luck with it.

For more information, here's a couple of snaps from the event log that might be of help:

[image: Picture showing event log error code]

[image: Picture showing event viewer item details.]

And finally, an XML dump from picture 3's details window:

```
Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-Backup
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Backup
Date:          6/10/2013 7:20:39 AM
Event ID:      5
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      ******
Description:
The backup operation that started at '‎2013‎-‎06‎-‎10T12:19:26.203012000Z' has failed with following error code '2147942487'. Please review the event details for a solution, and then rerun the backup operation once the issue is resolved.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Backup" Guid="{1DB28F2E-8F80-4027-8C5A-A11F7F10F62D}" />
    <EventID>5</EventID>
    <Version>2</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-06-10T12:20:39.944212000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>262</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="7992" ThreadID="5672" />
    <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Backup</Channel>
    <Computer>******</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="BackupTemplateID">{99B0DB5B-0D9C-4104-B80A-CB0DA8E1A81F}</Data>
    <Data Name="HRESULT">2147942487</Data>
    <Data Name="BackupState">12</Data>
    <Data Name="BackupTarget">Q:</Data>
    <Data Name="NumOfVolumes">2</Data>
    <Data Name="BackupTime">2013-06-10T12:19:26.203012000Z</Data>
    <Data Name="HRESULT2">2147942487</Data>
    <Data Name="VolumesInfo">&lt;VolumeInfo&gt;&lt;VolumeInfoItem Name="C:" OriginalAccessPath="C:" State="15" HResult="-2139619228" DetailedHResult="0" PreviousState="0" IsCritical="1" IsIncremental="0" BlockLevel="1" HasFiles="0" HasSystemState="0" IsCompacted="0" IsPruned="0" IsRecreateVhd="0" FullBackupReason="0" DataTransferred="0" NumUnreadableBytes="0" TotalSize="0" TotalNoOfFiles="0" Flags="1544" BackupTypeDetermined="0" SSBTotalNoOfFiles="0" SSBTotalSizeOnDisk="0" /&gt;&lt;VolumeInfoItem Name="D:" OriginalAccessPath="D:" State="15" HResult="-2139619228" DetailedHResult="0" PreviousState="0" IsCritical="0" IsIncremental="0" BlockLevel="1" HasFiles="0" HasSystemState="0" IsCompacted="0" IsPruned="0" IsRecreateVhd="0" FullBackupReason="0" DataTransferred="0" NumUnreadableBytes="0" TotalSize="0" TotalNoOfFiles="0" Flags="8" BackupTypeDetermined="0" SSBTotalNoOfFiles="0" SSBTotalSizeOnDisk="0" /&gt;&lt;/VolumeInfo&gt;</Data>
    <Data Name="DetailedHRESULT">0</Data>
    <Data Name="SourceSnapStartTime">2013-06-10T12:19:26.187412000Z</Data>
    <Data Name="SourceSnapEndTime">1601-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z</Data>
    <Data Name="PrepareBackupStartTime">&lt;TimesList&gt;&lt;Time Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /&gt;&lt;Time Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /&gt;&lt;/TimesList&gt;</Data>
    <Data Name="PrepareBackupEndTime">&lt;TimesList&gt;&lt;Time Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /&gt;&lt;Time Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /&gt;&lt;/TimesList&gt;</Data>
    <Data Name="BackupWriteStartTime">&lt;TimesList&gt;&lt;Time Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /&gt;&lt;Time Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /&gt;&lt;/TimesList&gt;</Data>
    <Data Name="BackupWriteEndTime">&lt;TimesList&gt;&lt;Time Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /&gt;&lt;Time Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /&gt;&lt;/TimesList&gt;</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetSnapStartTime">1601-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetSnapEndTime">1601-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z</Data>
    <Data Name="DVDFormatStartTime">&lt;TimesList&gt;&lt;/TimesList&gt;</Data>
    <Data Name="DVDFormatEndTime">&lt;TimesList&gt;&lt;/TimesList&gt;</Data>
    <Data Name="MediaVerifyStartTime">&lt;TimesList&gt;&lt;/TimesList&gt;</Data>
    <Data Name="MediaVerifyEndTime">&lt;TimesList&gt;&lt;/TimesList&gt;</Data>
    <Data Name="BackupPreviousState">2</Data>
    <Data Name="ComponentStatus">&lt;ComponentStatus&gt;&lt;/ComponentStatus&gt;</Data>
    <Data Name="SSBEnumerateStartTime">1601-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z</Data>
    <Data Name="SSBEnumerateEndTime">1601-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z</Data>
    <Data Name="SSBVhdCreationStartTime">1601-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z</Data>
    <Data Name="SSBVhdCreationEndTime">1601-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z</Data>
    <Data Name="SSBBackupStartTime">1601-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z</Data>
    <Data Name="SSBBackupEndTime">1601-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z</Data>
    <Data Name="SystemStateBackup">&lt;SystemState IsPresent="0" HResult="0" DetailedHResult="0" /&gt;</Data>
    <Data Name="BMR">false</Data>
    <Data Name="VssFullBackup">false</Data>
    <Data Name="UserInputBMR">false</Data>
    <Data Name="UserInputSSB">false</Data>
    <Data Name="BackupSuccessLogPath">
    </Data>
    <Data Name="BackupFailureLogPath">
    </Data>
    <Data Name="EnumerateBackupStartTime">&lt;TimesList&gt;&lt;Time Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /&gt;&lt;Time Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /&gt;&lt;/TimesList&gt;</Data>
    <Data Name="EnumerateBackupEndTime">&lt;TimesList&gt;&lt;Time Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /&gt;&lt;Time Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /&gt;&lt;/TimesList&gt;</Data>
    <Data Name="PruneBackupStartTime">&lt;TimesList&gt;&lt;Time Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /&gt;&lt;Time Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /&gt;&lt;/TimesList&gt;</Data>
    <Data Name="PruneBackupEndTime">&lt;TimesList&gt;&lt;Time Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /&gt;&lt;Time Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /&gt;&lt;/TimesList&gt;</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I am not sure if this is entirely useful - if additional details are needed, please let me know and I will append them to this as they become available by request.

EDIT: Forgot to specify some basic but important information:

OS - Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, Service Pack 1, 64-Bit

Comment: what about Q:? Network mapped drive?

Comment: did you tried to backup system stare only? If it fails, this may help: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsbackup/thread/0b0f2d9c-e3b1-4f85-a6d2-2e15e5a15bc1/

Answer (score 1):

From [Microsoft](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsbackup/thread/5e882fba-1e97-43c1-bfc1-9d769165da6f):

> Either your backup disk has a sector size greater than 512 bytes and
>   does not have emulation for 512 byte size I/O.  Hence backup may be
>   failing.  To check whether your disk allows 512 byte I/O, try quick
>   formatting a volume (some small test volume). Right click and chose
>   Format.  There you will find choice for "Allocation unit size".  Pick
>   512.  See if formatting is successful.
>
> Second possibility is that, the last sector of your C: may be corrupt.
>   Chkdsk does not detect this.  Try to extend or shrink the volume by 10
>   MB, and retry the backup.